# Spring Data MongoDB find query returning no results

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a mongodb collection with multiple documents of following structure

```
{
    "_id" : "...",
    "_class" : "...",
    ...
    "travelers" : [
        {
            "id": "12345",
            "type": "XYZ"
        },
        {
            "id": "67890",
            "type": "ABC"
        }],
    ...
}
```

Using spring data, I am able to fetch documents that have traveler type XYZ :

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("travelers.type").is("XYZ");
List<Something> something = mongoTemplate.find(query, Something.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
```

But if I switch the query to fetch by traveler id, I get no results:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("travelers.id").is("12345");
List<Something> something = mongoTemplate.find(query, Something.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
```

I enabled all logs and the outgoing query is `{"travelers.id" : "12345"}` which looks right. Running the query `{"travelers.id" : "12345"}` directly on the db returns the right results.

Other queries I have tried on the collection seem to work fine. I have tried both with & without index on travelers.id and no results in both cases. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please doublecheck that the id is indeed a string (and thus needs quotes) and not an integer?

Comment: have checked that. id is a string.

Comment: Are you sure that the COLLECTION_NAME matches the collection in mongo?

Comment: @frant.hartm - yes, the collection name is correct. as i mentioned, other queries with the same collection work just fine.

Comment: Try to rename the id field to something like travelerId - fields with "id" name get special treatment in mapping - see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#d0e5058

Comment: @frant.hartm - you're right. changing the field from "id" to "travelerId" makes it work. please add it as an answer and i'll accept it.

but it still doesn't explain why the query works when running directly on the db but not when running via spring data's mongo template? is this a spring data bug or a bad assumption on their end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fields with "id" name get special treatment in mapping - see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.id-handling

What happens is that spring data mapping translates id to "_id" for your query when you do:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("travelers.id").is("12345");
```

so the query going to mongo isn't

```
{"travelers.id" : "12345"}
```

but is

```
{"travelers._id" : "12345"}
```

The queries logged by spring data mongo are little bit different to what actually goes to mongo.

Strange thing is that spring data doesn't do this mapping when saving the data.

Rename the id field to something like travelerId will solves the issue.

Comment: This is a bit annoying, I can understand when it's a top-level document but when it is an object within a document they shouldn't be automatically forcing the mapping this way, they should take it as is.